# Rails 4 and JSON routing returns error in Firebug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, routes

I have implemented an AJAX call that renders a JSON response.After checking my Firebug Console, I can see that the call results in a 404 Not Found error.

In my Controller (test_rules_controller.rb)

```
    def rule_attributes
      @test = RuleModel.find(params[:rule_model_id]).rule_attributes
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @test }
      end
    end
```

In my Routes:

```
get "/rule_models/:rule_model_id:/rule_attributes" => "test_rules#rule_attributes", :as => "rule_attributes", :format => :json
```

I have also created a rule_attributes.json.jbuilder file in my test_rules view folder:

```
json.rule_attributes @test
```

I am not sure why it is resulting in this error as I've never used JSON with routes before (Rails Newbie). When I try to navigate to the same URL in the browser, it raises the error that no route matches the given route (http://localhost:3000/rule_models/1/rule_attributes.json).

Can anybody please help?

Comment: `get "/rule_models/:rule_model_id:/rule_attributes"` has an extra `:` after rule_model_id.

Comment: This is what happens if you work on an app for a few days with little sleep. Thank you